# Angularjs routing not working with version 1.5.6

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

This Piece of code works absolutely fine with cdn https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3//angular-route.min.js
but not with https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6//angular-route.min.js
Where is the issue?
config.js

```
    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);
    mainApp.config(['$locationProvider','$routeProvider',function($locationProvider,$routeProvider)
    {
    //  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider
          .when('/home', {
              templateUrl: 'home.html',
              controller: 'StudentController'
          })
          .when('/viewStudents', {
              templateUrl: 'viewStudents.html',
              controller: 'StudentController'
          })
          .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/home'
          });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, this might not be considered as answer you're looking for, but I was struggling exactly with the same problem and since then I'm using *$stateProvider* which works like a charm

the syntax is very similar

```
angular

    .module('app.routes', ['ionic'])
    .config(routing);

function routing($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')

    $stateProvider

    .state('layout', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/layout.html',
        controller: 'myCtl1',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
    })

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        cache: 'false',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'myCtl2',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
    })
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

See [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)

Starting with 1.3 you need to specify the base url. And remove the / from your routes, ie:

```
.when('/viewStudents' should be .when('viewStudents'
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

Or set requireBase to false

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

Prior to 1.3, what you have would work when deployed to root context--but would not work in a subcontext.